# Unset all product categories thumbnail in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, categories

Is there a way to set the thumbnail option to none for all WooCommerce categories?

I have to remove the thumbnails from 400+ categories and doing it one by one will take me way more than time I want it to...

I tried removing the images from my media library, but now there is no placeholder image on my categories and it just says "thumbnail" in the image on the admin edit product categories page.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a PHP, SQL, or plugin matter, but I'd be willing to try either of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all registered 'thumbnail_id' in your product categories you can use this function to be run once. **Make a backup before**. (This function works only for admin user roles).

Here is that code:

```
function remove_product_categories_thumbnail_id()
{
    // Working only for admin user roles
    if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : return;

    global $wpdb;

    $table_termmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "termmeta";
    $table_term_taxo = $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy";

    # Get ALL related Product category WP_Term objects (that have a thumbnail set)
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT * FROM $table_termmeta
        INNER JOIN $table_term_taxo ON $table_termmeta.term_id = $table_term_taxo.term_id
        WHERE $table_termmeta.meta_key LIKE 'thumbnail_id'
        AND $table_term_taxo.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
    ");

    // Storing all table rows ID related Product category (that have a thumbnail set)
    foreach($results as $result)
        $meta_ids_arr[] = $result->meta_id;

    // Convert the arry in a coma separated string of IDs
    $meta_ids_str = implode( ',', $meta_ids_arr );

    # DELETE ALL thumbmails IDs from Product Categories
    $wpdb->query( "
        DELETE FROM $table_termmeta
        WHERE $table_termmeta.meta_id  IN ($meta_ids_str)
    ");
}

## RUN THE FUNCTION ONCE ##

remove_product_categories_thumbnail_id();
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Browse any page of your site (backend or frontend) to run the script. Now you can remove this code.

Answer (score 1):

`do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );` this adds category_thumbnail to product categories, now you can do few things , force it return empty .

so remove this action call.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
```

with

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
```

or just comment out `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );` by overriding `content-product_cat.php` template.